# Improve FrameworkElementAdapters.ViewToContractAdapter

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, maf, system.addin

I'm using MAF(System.addin) with FrameworkElements between Host and AddIn.

I'm using FrameworkElementAdapters.ViewToContractAdapter and FrameworkElementAdapters.ContractToViewAdapter in the adpters.

I take times  of FrameworkElementAdapters.ViewToContractAdapter  with stopwatcher , and results in seconds is 1,3 s .

```
   public INativeHandleContract GetToolBox()
    {

        FrameworkElement e=view.GetControl();
        Stopwatch w = new Stopwatch();
        w.Start();
        INativeHandleContract c= FrameworkElementAdapters.ViewToContractAdapter(e);
        w.Stop();
        System.Console.WriteLine(w.Elapsed.TotalSeconds); ///Results is 1,3

        return c;
    }
```

Is it possible to improve time of FrameworkElementAdapters.ViewToContractAdapter ?

Thanks

Comment: 1,3s is too much as you say. Did you find out what caused the delay?

Comment: Even I do not know why it takes so much

Comment: I had the same problem. This solution helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155189/performance-of-the-frameworkelementadapters-class