# Performance of the FrameworkElementAdapters class

Tags: .net, wpf, performance, appdomain

Can't figure why cross-domain calls is so slow for `FrameworkElementAdapters` class. Here is a simple code:

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("AnotherDomain");

        var instance = (AnotherDomainClass) domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
            typeof (AnotherDomainClass).Assembly.FullName,
            typeof (AnotherDomainClass).FullName);

        var contract = instance.CreateContract();
    }
}

class AnotherDomainClass : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public INativeHandleContract CreateContract()
    {
        return FrameworkElementAdapters.ViewToContractAdapter(
            new TextBlock());
    }
}
```

The execution time of the last line `instance.CreateContract` is near **1.7 sec**! Where is a problem?

Comment: By posting this code, you have demonstrated that I can avoid using the Managed Add-In Framework's pipeline architecture, while at the same time still make use of unloadable plugins that provide FrameworkElements to the host app-domain.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried decorating your Main method with the [LoaderOptimizationAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.loaderoptimizationattribute%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) set to `LoaderOptimization.MultiDomainHost`?

The `FrameworkElementAdapters` class is part of System.AddIn. Have a look at [Add-In Performance: What can you expect as you cross an isolation boundary and how to make it better](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clraddins/archive/2008/02/22/add-in-performance-what-can-you-expect-as-you-cross-an-isolation-boundary-and-how-to-make-it-better-jesse-kaplan.aspx) form the blog of the System.AddIn team. Also have a look at the "Perfomance Optimization" section of the [WPF Add-Ins Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909794.aspx) MSDN article.

Comment: Great! Thanks! Execution time reduced to *0.09* sec!

Comment: And I noticed that this hint works only on clear execution (without visual studio host).